# Não consigo executar o Def em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Como faço para executar um `def` e um `return` em Python? Eu sempre faço no modo de edição e quando executo fica tudo em branco,não sai nada,alguém pode me explicar como executar?

Comment: Depende do que está fazendo, você não postou nada. Não disse como executou.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginando que escreveu uma função, tem que chamá-la, então se fez algo assim:

```
def funcao()
    return 1
```

precisa chamar assim:

```
funcao()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/Def.py).

Mas se só quer executar sem uma função aí não deve escrever um `def`.

Se quer aprender programar sugiro entender os conceitos, sair fazendo não ensina nada útil.

Comment: Cara, eu fiz desse jeito, eu ja aprendi bastante sobre conceitos, bom eu fiz um pequeno codigo que mede fatores, que também não sai nada fica em branco.   
  def fat (n):
    f = 1
    while n > 0:
        f = f * n
        n = n - 1
    return f

Comment: Então sua pergunta não diz qual é o problema.